# Replace a pattern present in multiple files with a value found in L10 character 7-11 of each file - UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed

#### Hello guys,

I was wondering if you could please help me with a UNIX command/set of commands that modifies all ".mos" files (which contain only lines with text) from current directory as follows:
I want to replace for each file individually "ExternalENodeBFunction=1" entry with "ExternalENodeBFunction=**ID**"

**ID** is read from line 10 character 7-11 of each file.
I know I can use the sed command to replace patterns with other strings , or awk command, but I do not know/understand how to replace with that specific string location.

Thank you very much for your help,

Catalin

PS  I added a picture with the input and the desired output

[image: input and wanted output]

Input:

```
#DoNotEditThisLine: =====================INPUT FILE==================

    gs+
    if $moshell_version ~ ^([7-9]|10)
       l echo "The moshell version is too old. 11.0a or higher is required for scripts containing the crn command."
       return
    fi
    
    crn ENodeBFunction=1,EUtraNetwork=1,ExternalENodeBFunction=1
    eNBId 42712
    eNodeBPlmnId 
    masterEnbFunctionId
    mfbiSupport 
    userLabel 
    end
    
    crn ENodeBFunction=1,EUtraNetwork=1,ExternalENodeBFunction=1,ExternalEUtranCellFDD=xxxx
    activePlmnList 
    activeServiceAreaId 
    csgPhysCellId 
    csgPhysCellIdRange 
    eutranFrequencyRef EUtraNetwork=1,EUtranFrequency=1325
    isRemoveAllowed false
    lbEUtranCellOffloadCapacity 
    localCellId
    masterEUtranCellFDDId xxxx
    pciConflict 
    pciConflictCell 
    pciDetectingCell 
    physicalLayerCellIdGroup
    physicalLayerSubCellId 
    tac 
    userLabel xxxx
    end
    
    crn ENodeBFunction=1,EUtranCellFDD=cell0042753L3,EUtranFreqRelation=1325,EUtranCellRelation=22299-42712-1
    cellIndividualOffsetEUtran 
    coverageIndicator 
    includeInSystemInformation 
    isHoAllowed 
    isRemoveAllowed 
    lbBnrAllowed 
    loadBalancing 
    neighborCellRef EUtraNetwork=1,ExternalENodeBFunction=1,ExternalEUtranCellFDD=xxxx
    qOffsetCellEUtran
    sCellCandidate
    end
    gs-
```

Output:

```
        #DoNotEditThisLine: ===============OUTPUT FILE==================
    
    gs+
    if $moshell_version ~ ^([7-9]|10)
       l echo "The moshell version is too old. 11.0a or higher is required for scripts containing the crn command."
       return
    fi
    
    crn ENodeBFunction=1,EUtraNetwork=1,ExternalENodeBFunction=42712
    eNBId 42712
    eNodeBPlmnId 
    masterEnbFunctionId
    mfbiSupport 
    userLabel 
    end
    
    crn ENodeBFunction=1,EUtraNetwork=1,ExternalENodeBFunction=42712,ExternalEUtranCellFDD=xxxx
    activePlmnList 
    activeServiceAreaId 
    csgPhysCellId 
    csgPhysCellIdRange 
    eutranFrequencyRef EUtraNetwork=1,EUtranFrequency=1325
    isRemoveAllowed false
    lbEUtranCellOffloadCapacity 
    localCellId
    masterEUtranCellFDDId xxxx
    pciConflict 
    pciConflictCell 
    pciDetectingCell 
    physicalLayerCellIdGroup
    physicalLayerSubCellId 
    tac 
    userLabel xxxx
    end
    
    crn ENodeBFunction=1,EUtranCellFDD=cell0042753L3,EUtranFreqRelation=1325,EUtranCellRelation=xxxxx
    cellIndividualOffsetEUtran 
    coverageIndicator 
    includeInSystemInformation 
    isHoAllowed 
    isRemoveAllowed 
    lbBnrAllowed 
    loadBalancing 
    neighborCellRef EUtraNetwork=1,ExternalENodeBFunction=42712,ExternalEUtranCellFDD=xxxx
    qOffsetCellEUtran
    sCellCandidate
    end
    gs-
```

Comment: for info, maybe a small sample of a `.mos` file, could be helpfull for awk

Comment: Is this entry ExternalENodeBFunction before or after line 10?

Comment: I added a new picture to show the input and desired output

Comment: Stop posting pictures and post text instead. We need sample input and expected output that we can test a potential solution against. Once we have that - the solution will be clear, brief, and simple in awk.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the text as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something like this:

```
awk '
NR < 10 {
    buf[NR] = $0
}
NR == 10 {
    eNBId = $2
    for (i=1; i<NR; i++) {
        sub(/ExternalENodeBFunction=[0-9]+/,"ExternalENodeBFunction="eNBId,buf[i])
        print buf[i]
    }
    print
}
NR > 10 {
    sub(/ExternalENodeBFunction=[0-9]+/,"ExternalENodeBFunction="eNBId)
    print
}
' file
```

but it's obviously untested since you didn't provide any sample input/output that we could test against.

Comment: You're welcome. I assume it's easy for you to read/understand too. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Any time you need to do anything more interesting than that you should use awk. Any time you find yourself using sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) you again should be using awk as all those other sed constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Comment: Thanks a lot again ! It's easy to understand it indeed. I will start reading on the awk command now :)) got a lot to catch up to

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ': load
# load lines (1 by 1) until Not last one
   $ !{N;b load
      }
# keep a copy into holding buffer
      h
# Extracting the number to substitute
   s/^\([[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]]*\n\)\{9\}.\{6\}\(....\).*/\2/
# add all the line after this (1st line is the number)
   G
: repl
# replace last occurence of External with the new reference
   s/^\(....\)\(.*\)\(ExternalENodeBFunction=\)1\([^0-9]\)/\1\2\3\1\4/
# if replacement occur, (re)try another one
   t repl
# cleanning by removing first number (4 digit + 1 new line)
   s/.....//
   ' YourFile
```

- a find (or grep in a loop) with this sed will give you all wanted file to transform
- Assuming there is a 10th line with info (script is not securized for this here but could be easy)
- Need to load file in memory (twice) so not the best for huge file (don't know .mos average file size, hope it is not 1 Gb)
- assuming file is not ending by a *External* to change (could be adapted if needed) like in sample

Comment: Sorry, but could you please explain the syntax a bit ? It is not working at the moment when I try running on 1 file, I am trying to understand why.

Comment: it was due to the double quote you specify in OP but that are not present in sample. I adapt for this and add some comment inside the code